# Placement of "to-infinitive" before an object

Tags: infinitives, to-infinitive, direct-objects, indirect-objects

1. David wants to bring Jack some books.
2. David wants Jack to bring some books.

I cannot understand the meanings of these sentences. What do they mean? Are both same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. means that David wants to bring some books **to** Jack, i.e. **David** will be the one bringing the books.
2. means that David wants that **Jack** will be the one that brings the books (it isn't specified where to).

So both sentences mean something completely different - word order is very important to distinguish between the direct and indirect object as English has no declensions for this purpose like some other languages do.

Comment: Just wondering: does *fior* exist? Or is it just a typo?